# Getting merged color satellite image from red,green, blue, pan, and nir tifs

Tags: qgis, satellite

I am using Tiff images from Digital Globe and trying to get a color satellite image. I have merged the red, green, blue, pan and nir tiff files into one file. I then changed the band properties to a max of 500 and contrasted enhancement to stretch and clip to the min and max values. Doing all this produced a merged satellite image but the image has no color and is being rendered as single band gray.

How can I create a colored image?

I'm assuming I need to somehow create a tif such that each red, blue, green, nir band is a band for the tiff.

Comment: did you make a single or multiband raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS Desktop - use the Raster->Miscellaneous->Build Virtual Raster (Catalog) tool. Make sure to tick the "Separate" option. This will put each input file into a separate stacked band instead of mosaicing to a single band. If you used this tool already, this may be why you are getting a single band as output.